# How to access static HTML website from s3 Private bucket in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have created a new private bucket in AWS S3. In this bucket i have 4 folders like A,B,C and D. In these folders i have uploaded index.html with JS and Images which act as static HTML website.

Now i have a website for example (www.test.com) in this website Home Page A,B,C and D's access link are given.On click these links, I want to get these running as HTML website but i am getting error page.
I am using iframe to access Bucket Folders.

Please find the attachment.
[image]

Is there a way to pass anytype of security token or session token so only authorised user can only access bucket content ?
Any suggestion on this.

Thank you,
Digvijay

Comment: you need a aws sdk for PHP to pass access_token etc to access S3 Bucket

Comment: I tried with access token, but direct image URls are accessible as we can not run static HTML until we do not declare these folder Public.

Comment: @Daga what is the application for this?  Is this a preview/staging/demo environment, or production? Finding the most suitable approach may depend on a better understanding of what exactly you are trying to accomplish, and for what purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Allow public read to the objects in your bucket and enable the static website feature. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html
2. You will need to create a CloudFront distribution that uses an S3 bucket endpoint (NOT an S3 static website endpoint) as origin, configure a CloudFront origin identity, add a custom 404 error page on the CloudFront distribution and configure a bucket policy grating GetObject and ListBucket permissions to the CloudFront identity.

The first one is pretty easy and straight forward to do if you can allow public-read to the objects in the bucket I would recommend that. The second one involves more AWS knowledge. I wrote an extensive article on how to do it including the security concerns you should be aware of (https://emagalha.es/blog/2020/05/07/securing-s3-static-websites/). Also if you are lazy you can simply use the CloudFormatio template I created to build the base infrastructure (https://github.com/ericovis/aws-secure-static-websites)